# How can DIV container (with Position: fixed) get it's height and width? (Using % for units)

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how can I get a child of a DIV container with Position: fixed to fit into the parent container. I am trying to get the div "text-manager" to fully fit inside it's parent which is "top-bar"

Thanks!

```css
    body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #EFEFEF;
     font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
     height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .top-bar {
     position: fixed;
     left: 20%;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 1100px;
     height: 6%;
     background-color: red;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    
    .top-bar .text-manager {
     width: inherit;
        max-width: inherit;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: green;
    }
    
    .side-bar {
     position: fixed;
     width: 20%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #2E3E4E;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Homepage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <head>
     <title>Cold-Ops Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top-bar">
       <div class="text-manager">
        <p>Some more text</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="side-bar">
    
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a `user agent style sheet` being applied to the `p` tag which has a `margin` of `1em` being set. The below code works, additionally avoid giving fixed widths and heights to `fixed` position elements , let them adjust their widths and heights according to their contents

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  height: 6%;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.top-bar .text-manager {
  width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.top-bar .text-manager p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2E3E4E;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<head>
  <title>Cold-Ops Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="text-manager">
        <p>Some more text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-bar">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! The explanation really helped! But how did the p tag get a margin of 1em? And what is a user agent style sheet? Last question, do I avoid giving fixed widths even if I am using max-width? If so, is there an alternative solution so that I do not have to give a fixed width in this case? Thank you again!

Comment: each browser gives its own default style sheets to each and every element this enables them to present each element separately and neatly as opposed to them just cluttering at the top left corner of the browser, these are called `user agent style sheets`

Comment: Gotcha! And how did the p tag get it's margin of 1em?

Comment: if you inspect the p tag in google chrome then it gets a `user agent style sheet` applied which gives it a `1em` margin.

Comment: The best way to avoid these unexpected layouts would be to include a `reset.css`  as the first css style sheet to load , read more here: https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/ . All other style sheets come after this, alternatively if you use a css frame work such as bootstrap, materialize etc the css reset is included by default

Comment: Wow. That was really helpful! Cheers for the link! Thanks again! :)

Comment: As for your other question, just leave the `width` to `100%` and the height to `auto` that should make your element with `fixed` position accommodate taller elements. However if you're going for a look where in the div overflows out from its containing element with the `fixed` position then fixed heights in `px` might be a good idea

Comment: I set the width to 100% and the height to auto for the .text-manager div? I am not looking for my div to overflow elements that cannot fit inside the div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172853/discussion-between-immortal-dude-and-omar-dajani).

Answer (score 1):

Add  a relative position div around the `text-manager` div and make the `text-manager` positioned absolute in it.

```
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div class="text-manager" style="position: absolute;top:0; left:0;height:100%;">
                        <p>Some more text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```css
    body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #EFEFEF;
     font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
     height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .top-bar {
     position: fixed;
     left: 20%;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 1100px;
     height: 6%;
     background-color: red;
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    
    .top-bar .text-manager {
     width: inherit;
        max-width: inherit;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: green;
    }
    
    .side-bar {
     position: fixed;
     width: 20%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #2E3E4E;
    } 
    p {
       margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Homepage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <head>
     <title>Cold-Ops Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top-bar">
                <div style="position: relative;">
            <div class="text-manager" style="position: absolute;top:0; left:0;height:100%;">
            <p>Some more text</p>
           </div>
                </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="side-bar">
    
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! But can you please explain what you did?

Comment: This is all really confusing haha, but thanks for your answer! Is this the most efficient way to do this using your code above?

Comment: No i liked the other answer also. I missed that you had applied height on the fixed div.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks again! :)